# Typed dataset gives object reference not set error

Tags: c#, asp.net, dataset

I am working on an asp.net application and I am using typed data sets. I have added a table adapter and data table to already developed Dataset. It works on my local system but when I publish my website using right click and deploy and upload to live server.

I get error on this line:

```
FoldersTableAdapter vta = new FoldersTableAdapter();
int vacancyId = (int)vta.Update(ItemID, ResumeFolderName.Text, EmployeeID, 0, false);
```

Error is:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: may be EmployeeID null ? or itemID ? any one of the thing is null

Comment: I printed them out in catch block and they all have values.

Comment: paste more code,,if these lines are error free then sure your next line of code will have error

Comment: @TimSchmelter: I used debugger but locally nothing is null. I printed this in exception EmployeeID.ToString() + ResumeFolderName.Text + ItemID.ToString () + ex.Message  and it returns 10CVFolder0Object reference not set ...